# Angular table: how to force conditional-based column update after condition change

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am working with a table component in which rows can be marked/unmarked as favourites by clicking on a star icon in a dedicated column:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows cellpadding="10">
  ...        
  <ng-container *ngIf="col.name === 'fav'" matColumnDef="fav">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="!isFaved(row)" (click)="favRow(row)"><mat-icon>star_border</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="isFaved(row)" (click)="unfavRow(row, false)"><mat-icon>star</mat-icon></button>
      </td>
  </ng-container>
  ...
</table>
```

This works perfectly: by clicking the icon, the row is marked as favourite, the **isFaved(row)** returns true and the icon is updated accordingly.

The same works the other way around: when clicking the icon for a fav row, the row is unmarked as favourite, the **isFaved(row)** returns false and the icon is updated.

---

I also have a secondary use case in which the favourite state of a row can be changed by the parent component.

This also works partly: the table gets the information regarding which row to unfavourite, and the knowledge in the table component is correctly updated, so **isFaved(row)** would return the correct information.

Unfortunately, nothing triggers this function, since there was no click on the fav icon, so the icon is incorrectly left in the fav state until I manually refresh the page.

How can I deal with this case? Is there something more elegant than cranking out a dummy click event?

Comment: Can you show the code on how the parent component communicates to the child component to update the data? On another note, have a look at the [MatTable](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable) documentation here and the `renderRows()` function. Calling this function after the parent has updated the data might solve your problem.

Comment: I am using this pattern to communicate the information that a favourited row should be toggled: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter